# OAuth - Authorization server if hosted on web farm how to generate bearer token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, owin

we have formsauthentication using Machine keys if it is to be hosted on web farm

How can I host authorization server (say WebAPI) in web farm which will produce same bearer token  ?

Do I need to setup same Machine Key configuration on all servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to setup same Machine Key configuration on all servers?

If you're using the OAuth2 authorization server that is part of OWIN/Katana (`OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware`), yes.